# Import Feed in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, rss, importerror

I would like to import this in sheet doc. I am creating a Dashboard and would love to use the RSS feed to populate the live updates. however, after using the `importfeed` function or `import url` function it saves indicating the syntax is correct however no data is populated. Any help here?

[image]